# Why do I not get a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrix, symmetric

expected symmetric matrix

[image: 1]

Why is the resulting matrix not symmetrical?
Jim

Hand multiplication gives a matrix that is not symmetrical

Comment: This is purely a math question, so it is off topic for Stack Overflow. But the product of two symmetric matrices is **not** always symmetric.

Comment: As this is not a programming or software development question, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow.  I recommend math.stackexchange.com.  This looks to be an answer to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3791939/518129